# Use Case for action "shooting"

Tags: model, uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

I am required to create a use diagram for a requirement in a game where a player shoots another player. Now, I am getting very confused with what the use cases in the diagram should be. Should these be: shoot projectile, show projectile, verify hit, remove projectile and update score (and then should they have include relationships as they follow each other or should this be done differently?). Or is this too specific since these are not direct interactions with the actor (the player) and do I just have the use case (shoot projectile). Hopefully someone can help me out!

I have the following Use Case, but am thus unsure about the connections to be made + if the use cases so far are correct.

Answer (score 0):

A use case is never about the HOW but about the WHAT. It shows added value a system under consideration brings to its actors. All you are talking is about HOW and this is targeted in Activities/Actions.

I recommend to read Bittner/Spence about Use Cases.